# Why does python subprocess zip fail but running at shell works?

Tags: python, shell, zip

I'm on Mac OS X using Python 2.7; using `subprocess.call` with `zip` fails yet running the *same command* at the shell succeeds. Here's a copy of my terminal:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['zip', 'example.zip', 'example/*'])
    zip warning: name not matched: example/*

zip error: Nothing to do! (example.zip)
12
>>> quit()
$ zip example.zip example/*
  adding: example/file.gz (deflated 0%)
```

I've also tried with full paths and had the same result.

Comment: Behaviour is system-dependent and works on Windows, while fails on *nix due reasons explained by @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because running a command in the shell is not the same thing as running it with `subprocess.call()`; the shell expanded the `example/*` wildcard.

Either expand the list of files with `os.listdir()` or the `glob` module yourself, or run the command through the shell from Python; with the `shell=True` argument to `subprocess.call()` (but make the first argument a whitespace-separated string).

Using [`glob.glob()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) is probably the best option here:

```
import glob
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['zip', 'example.zip'] + glob.glob('example/*'))
```

Comment: Why don't we use https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zipfile.html module in python. Is there any difference between both methods ?

Comment: @C.R.Sharat: the question is about why the glob wasn't being expanded. You'll have to ask the OP why they prefer using the command-line tool over the Python module.

Answer (score 2):

Martijn's advice to use [`glob.glob`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) is good for general shell wildcards, but in this case it looks as if you want to add all files in a directory to the ZIP archive. If that's right, you might be able to use the `-r` option to [`zip`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip):

```
directory = 'example'
subprocess.call(['zip', '-r', 'example.zip', directory])
```

Comment: Good answer, but I think the order should be `subprocess.call(['zip', '-r',  'example.zip', directory])`.

Answer (score 0):

Try shell=True. subprocess.call('zip example.zip example/*', shell=True) would work.

Comment: shell=True can cause security problems, but it does enable shell globbing; `glob.glob` is a better answer